# How to show a message in two lines in the alert() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using alert function to show a message. But I want to show this message in two lines. The message is "The transaction has been approved. Thank you".
The code is:

```
alert('The transaction has been approved. Thank you');
```

The result should be:

> **The transaction has been approved.**
>
> **Thank you**

Comment: `alert('The transaction has been approved.\n Thank you');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a newline `\n` character.

```js
alert('The transaction has been approved.\nThank you');
//                                       ^^
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert('The transaction has been approved.\n\nThank you');
```

Actually looks like two(2) new line breaks `\n` are what you're after, to be specific, per the spacing in your desired output.